# Merging multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, merge

I have 2 array as below(Array-1, Array-2) and i wanted to merge as a single array as below (New-Array) based on the below condition

Contition : (if Array-1(hID) = Array-2(hID) then megre as below)

Array-1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 107
            [env] => DEV
            [serv] => server1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 122
            [env] => DEV
            [serv] => server2
        )
```

Array-2

```
Array
(
    [107] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 107
            [cpu] => 32
            [mem] => 24
        )

    [122] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 122
            [cpu] => 16
            [mem] => 24
        )
```

New-Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 107
            [env] => DEV
            [serv] => server1
            [cpu] => 32
            [mem] => 24
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [hID] => 122
            [env] => DEV
            [serv] => server2
            [cpu] => 16
            [mem] => 24
        )
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If second array **always** has same keys as `hID` values then you can do the following:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    if (isset($array2[$item['hID']])) {
        $newArray[] = array_merge($item, $array2[$item['hID']]);
    }
}
```

Or you can always create such array (key is the same as hID value) with:

```
$array2 = array_combine(
    array_column($array2, 'hID'),
    $array2
);
```

Comment: Can you please reconfirm the second code whether the above logic is correct as there is no array1 mentioned.

Comment: Second code is for rebuilding second array. It doesn't solve your task, just helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

**The test arrays** :

```
$array_1 = [
    0 => [
        "hID" => 107,
        "env" => "DEV",
        "serv" => "server1"
    ],
    1 => [
        "hID" => 122,
        "env" => "DEV",
        "serv" => "server2"
    ] 
];

$array_2 = [
    0 => [
        "hID" => 107,
        "cpu" => 32,
        "mem" => 24
    ],
    1 => [
        "hID" => 122,
        "cpu" => 16,
        "mem" => 24
    ] 
];
```

**The code to merge both arrays** :

```
$new_array = [];
 for($i=0;$i<count($array_1);$i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<count($array_2);$j++) {
        if ($array_1[$i]['hID'] === $array_2[$j]['hID']) {
            $new_array[] = array_merge($array_1[$i], $array_2[$j]);
        }
    }
 }
```

**The output :**

```
 var_dump($new_array);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["hID"]=>
    int(107)
    ["env"]=>
    string(3) "DEV"
    ["serv"]=>
    string(7) "server1"
    ["cpu"]=>
    int(32)
    ["mem"]=>
    int(24)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["hID"]=>
    int(122)
    ["env"]=>
    string(3) "DEV"
    ["serv"]=>
    string(7) "server2"
    ["cpu"]=>
    int(16)
    ["mem"]=>
    int(24)
  }
}
```

Test here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
if($array1[hID] == $array2[hID]){
```

$Array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
}